# Setup an alert email for multiple similar inbound emails within a short timeframe

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-outlook-365

Don't know if this is the right place for this question. But hopeful for some answers or ideas.

The situation:
We set up some forms that send us emails on multiple website with support questions.
So the subject of the emails are sturctured the same, starting with categories and then the problem.

Individual questions or alerts are ok, they will be responded to within 4-8hours.

But when there is a larger issue, we get 10+ emails within the same category within, say 10mins.
A clear indication that something is larger is wrong.

We would like to setup an alert email, to a different email address, that sends a notification if say 5 emails with the same subject are received within 10mins. So a specific person gets notified that a larger issue is at hand. But all rules etc. you can setup in outlook or with power-automate seem to focus on singlar email messages.

Comment: I'm not aware of such solution built-into Office. You could create Powershell script checking the mailbox and then processing emails (either PS imap client or MailboxSearch snippet on Exchange server), but it's nowhere in "comfortable and reliable" area. IMHO, It would be definitively best to add such functionality on webserver side as added form code. Is it possible here?

Comment: I don't see how, it is coming from multiple scripts/servers/websites.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use [Microsoft Purview's alert policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/alert-policies) feature to create an alert policy that generates an alert and sends an email notification to you or others when an email that matches certain criteria is received.
- Another possible method is to use [Microsoft Defender for Office 365's quarantine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/quarantine-quarantine-notifications?view=o365-worldwide) feature to quarantine suspicious or malicious emails and send quarantine notifications to recipients or administrators.